# How to use user entered value in all the jsp pages in application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In this scenario im having a login.jsp and 4 other jsps like file1.jsp,file2.jsp,file3.jsp and file4.jsp.

login.jsp Code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="application" method="post">
UserName : <input type="text" name="uname" > <br><br>
password : <input type="password"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i Submit the form it goes to ApplicationServlet.java and the code is :

```
 @WebServlet("/application")
 public class ApplicationServlet extends HttpServlet {

 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
 throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = req.getParameter("uname");

    System.out.println("Entered username is : " + username);

    req.setAttribute("user", username);
    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("File1.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, resp);
} }
```

then i forwarded the request to file1.jsp here is the code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
<%
    String name = (String)request.getAttribute("user");  %>
    Welcome <%=name %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in file1.jsp im able to display the user entered value.

but when im using the same thing in file2.jsp im getting null.

file2.jsp code is

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <% String name = (String)request.getAttribute("user");  %>
  Welcome <%=name %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How can i reuse the user entered value in other jsp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use HttpSession for setting value in you servlet after successful login.

Eg:

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", name);

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 scope of a variable in JSP.

1. page
2. request
3. session
4. application.

use session scope if you want your variables in all pages for limited period of time.

use application scope if you want to retain values of your variable all the time.

for more understanding, read these 4 implicit objects in JSP. Total 9 implicit objects are there.